# How to remove // TODO Auto-generated method stub in Servlet template in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, comments

I know the method to remove this in a normal function, which is the code template way: window -> preferences -> Java code template. but what about the stubborn one while creating a servlet using built-in servlet template? (New -> Servlet )
[image]